# FCTRL - Factorial on SPOJ

Tags: c#, algorithm

Can anyone help me with what mistake am I making ? This is just a simple problem to calculate *trailing zeroes* for *number's factorial*.

The output works successully on Ideone, but for some reason throws

> "Wrong answer"

on SPOJ's compiler.

Can someone please *spot the mistake* that I'm making.

https://ideone.com/BTVOfu

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numberOfValues = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] values = new int[numberOfValues];

        for(int i=0;i<numberOfValues;i++)
        {
            values[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(calculateFact(values[i]));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int calculateFact(int value)
    {
        int finalValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; value > 5; i++)
        {
            value = value / 5;
            finalValue += value;
        }

        return finalValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the initial task/problem you are solving? Given `N` find out number of trailing zeros of `N!`?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava It says "wrong answer"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes. Input a number 'N' and to find the trailing zeroes for N!

Comment: Can you try hard coding the values just to check if your logic is fine.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava Works for me. https://ideone.com/xCg4GF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very time to implement and run *some tests* to find out "wrong answer"s:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

...

// Slow, ugly but easy to understand and check routine
static int naiveCount(int value) {
  BigInteger factorial = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= value; ++i)
    factorial *= i;

  return factorial.ToString().Length - factorial.ToString().TrimEnd('0').Length;
}

...

var counterExamples = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 100)
  .Select(v => new {
     value = v,
     actual = calculateFact(v),
     expected = naiveCount(v), })
  .Where(item => item.expected != item.actual)
  .Select(item => $"value: {item.value,4} actual: {item.actual,3} expected: {item.expected,3}");

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, counterExamples));
```

Outcome:

```
value:    5 actual:   0 expected:   1
value:   25 actual:   5 expected:   6
value:   26 actual:   5 expected:   6
value:   27 actual:   5 expected:   6
value:   28 actual:   5 expected:   6
value:   29 actual:   5 expected:   6
```

When having *counter examples*, it's easy to *debug* for instance `calculateFact(5)` case. Can you see the problem now? It's in the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; value > 5; i++)
```

which should be (`>=` instead of `>`)

```
for (int i = 0; value >= 5; i++)
```

**Edit**: Technically, all you have to do is to check powers of `5`:

```
static int calculateFact(int value) {
  int result = 0;

  // 13 loops = floor(log(2**31)/log(5))
  for (int power5 = 5; power5 <= int.MaxValue / 5; power5 *= 5) 
    result += value / power5;

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably get an out-of-memory error. You don't need an `int[] values`. You can calculate the factorial immediately after reading a number. And you don't need the `Console.ReadKey();`. Note that I haven't checked the correctness of `calculateFact`.

And as noted by Dmitry, your function is wrong... You are "off by one":

```
for (int i = 0; value >= 5; i++)
```

See the `>=`? But you can speed it up a little by removing the `i` variable.

```
static int calculateFact(int value)
{
    int finalValue = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        value /= 5;

        if (value == 0)
        {
            return finalValue;
        }

        finalValue += value;
    }
}
```

This should be correct, but I'm not sure it is fast enough (often SPOJ problems are based on "caching" data)